# Tkinter - Entry output in popup

Tags: python, tkinter

i need a function that can user

Enter Kilobyte (KB) value in entry widget

result popup in Megabyte (MB)

using tkinter

Comment: i'm building app using GUI with tkinter , i need user input KB value and mechine result popup in MB

Comment: please, post you attempt and doubts before asking for a code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(column=0, row=0)

def convert():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="MB", message=int(entry.get())/1000)

button = tk.Button(root, text='button', command=convert)
button.grid(column=1, row=0)




root.mainloop()
```